# Ломается телеграмм бот когда два пользователя вводят данные одновременно

Tags: python, telebot

И так у меня есть телеграмм бот(созданный с помощью pyTelegramBotAPI), который просит пользователя ввести его тип темперамента и сохраняет его в файл на ПК. Вроде я все учел и создал словарь где ключи это `id` чата и значение это тип темперамента. НО если два пользователя введут данные одновременно то одному из пользователей не присвоется значение темперамента. Что делать?

Comment: Попробуйте использовать БД

Comment: Prog, а что это?

Comment: БД - базы данных. их немало, конкретно в вашем случае используйте sqlite3 (есть много обучалок)

Comment: Хмм, спасибо надо попробовать)